# AjaxControlToolkit HtmlEditorExtender newline behaviour change

Tags: c#, html

I am trying to use AjaxControlToolkit for simple HTML page revisions and updates. However, recently I found quite odd behaviour.

When pressing enter (to make some new lines) the editor does not write 
. Instead, it wraps the remaining part of text in TextBox into a  or . This, however causes trouble when inserting new line in various places inside the HTML code. Many times, something like this was generated:

```
some text
<div><div><span> some more text </div> </span> </div>
```

which broke the page. In fact, I only wanted to get:

```
some text
<br />
<br />
&nbsp; some more text
```

I have come around this by replacing those tags with empty strings in code behind, before saving the text. However, sometimes I get  with some width attributes and I am unable to catch all possibilities.

Is there a way how to change this behaviour? I am using the HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider sanitizer.

Comment: IMHO The best free editor.... http://ckeditor.com/

Comment: Not the answer I expected, but I will give it a try. Thank you for the tip.